# Role of command-runner.jar and script-runner.jar in aws emr

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

When we execute a spark job in emr cluster,we add step as

```
'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Args': [
                    'spark-submit',
                    's3://spark-test-bucket-pr/spark_job/spark_job_3.py'
                ],
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar'
            }
```

Want to understand what is the role of 'command-runner.jar' file here. Because when we run spark job in on-premise hadoop cluster we dont use any such jar.
Also to execute shell script in emr we use script-runner.jar file.
So anyone can make me understand the role of these two jars and why we need them to execuute spark jobs in EMR cluster?

Answer (score 1):

These are helper jar files provided by AWS. When you run on-premise, you are directly talking to the hadoop cluster. But with AWS EMR, you have an extra layer of AWS specific interfaces.

You can run the same EMR job with either of the `script-runner` or `command-runner`. AFAIK, with command-runner you could also specify a custom jar file that has your business logic.

More details with examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html#emr-commandrunner-examples